# Why there is no copy button for tex code area?

Tags: feature-request

Why there is no copy button for TeX code area in [TSE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/) like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) code area?

Comment: The codecopy extension allows you to copy the code to Chrome and firefox: https://github.com/zenorocha/codecopy

Comment: I see no copy button on stackoverflow, are you running a user javascript that adds a button to some sites but not others?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/6576302 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753609/6576302